# How to update the database automatically after session is expired without refreshing on my page

Tags: php, mysql, session

This code you need to refresh or click the page before it will go to index page and before it will update the database after the session is expired.

How can I make it automatically that after session is expired it will update the database so the user active will be 0 without refreshing or clicking on page?

```
$idletime = 3600; //after 1hr the user gets logged out

if (time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'] >= $idletime){
    $online = "UPDATE users SET active = 0 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    mysqli_query($con, $online);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
} else {
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a different approach here.
You should not update the 'active' field in the database. Otherwise you create 'lastActivity' field in the DB and update it every time user do something on the site.

In this case you can easily detect which users are inactive by querying the database like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lastActivity < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Your PHP code will look like:

```
$online = "UPDATE users SET lastActive = NOW() WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
mysqli_query($con, $online);
```

Comment: SNAP :-) Nice to see my thinking isn't off the mark.

Comment: Sir Step and Sir Kevin, I used Active because I'm using badge that if the user is active the badge color is green like facebook. So in my code, the update query will not take effect unless you refresh the page ..   So is there any way that even without refreshing it will update the database? thx

Comment: In the script where you decide which badge to display instead of doing SQL like '... WHERE active = 1 ...' do the SQL like I showed in my example.

Comment: Another question  because I'm just new on this active user code. What will update on the lastActivity?  Is it the time? or What will I insert on the lastActivity? is it session['timestamp'];  ? Thankyou

Comment: You need to put there the last user activity time. You're correct. lastActivity is the same as `session['timestamp']` in your code. NOW() function of MySQL do it for you. So at every given time you can tell how much time passed since user did anything on the site. Based on it you can determine if he is active or not

Comment: @Stepashka, I just submitted an update to your submission to change `DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. `DATE` functions return just the date part without the time :-)

Comment: ah ok Got it.. I just add it on my database. Sir step. SELECT * FROM users WHERE lastActivity < DATE(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);   it has syntax error.   Im just new of this code in SQL can you help me please where is the error? thanks alot

Comment: Thank you sir step n sir kevin :)

Answer (score 5):

Best option is to not use an active/not active flag in the database, but rather use something like a `last_active` timestamp. When the user accesses a page, update the timestamp to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`. And to determine whether the user is currently active, query for `WHERE active_timestamp < TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, -60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())`

Make sure you set `active_timestamp` as a `DATETIME` type in the table structure. (`ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN active_timestamp datetime AFTER username'`)

The problem here is that your script looks to want to kick the user out when the session is idle. For this, you should look at JavaScript, set a timer that counts down over 1 hour and if there is no activity, redirect the page.