# How to update database when session expires automatically in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-timeout

I am updating login and logout date & time of all users who logs into my website , When they click on logout at that time i am saving logout time of that particular user but when session expires automatically i am not able to update logout date & time .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987521/how-to-update-the-database-automatically-after-session-is-expired-without-refres

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam how should i implement same with codeigniter ? i have seen this quesion before asking ? Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to you have to extend CI_Session

Create a php file inside `application/core/MY_Session.php`

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function sess_destroy() {

    //write your update here 
    $this->CI->db->update('YOUR_TABLE', array('YOUR_DATA'), array('YOUR_CONDITION'));

    //call the parent 
    parent::sess_destroy();
}

}
```

Comment: $login_user_id=$this->session->login_user_id;
 $this->db->set('logout_detail_datetime', 'NOW()', FALSE);
 $this->db->where('login_detail_id', $login_user_id);
 $this->db->update('login_details');
  i am doing this //call the parent 
    parent::sess_destroy();

Comment: $login_user_id=$this->session->login_user_id;
 $array = array('logout_detail_datetime'=> NOW());
 $this->CI->db->update('login_details', $array, $this->db->where('login_detail_id', $login_user_id)); parent::sess_destroy();

Comment: Ok i will try this ? Will it really create some difference ?

Comment: Do i need to change anything in Config file >

Comment: You might also want to add 'session' to your config/autoload.php:

$autoload['libraries'] = array('session',....)

Comment: sure i will do that

Comment: values are stil not updating in database when session is automatically expired

Comment: try it $autoload['libraries'] = array( 'MY_Session');

Comment: still not working is there any other way to do this ?